# Create all possible dictionary-based words from a set of letters - Tips to improve processing speed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small project where I must unscramble (find all possible words that can be written using only letter(s) in a set of letters) 100 000 lettersets, each letterset contain 12 letters. I would like to find the best way in terms of speed to handle this task in Python. So far, it took me already 10 hours but the command has not finished running yet.

I have looked at the exact problem in other posts and saw the permutation method from itertools. I think it's a lot slower than this method that I borrow from a website (code below). In fact, one permutation of a 12-letter letterset already take a significant amount of time for my laptop. Or maybe I misunderstand something.

The dictionary I'm working with is Spanish. For presentation purpose, I generate letterset as 1 string, instead of a list.

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','á','é','í','ó','ú','ü']

def randomString(stringLength=12):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
```

Define unscramble function

```
def charCount(word):
    dict = {}
    for i in word:
        dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1
    return dict


def possible_words(vocab, letterset):
    unscrambled_words = []
    for word in vocab:
        flag = 1
        chars = charCount(word)
        for key in chars:
            if key not in letterset:
                flag = 0
            else:
                if letterset.count(key) != chars[key]:
                    flag = 0
        if flag == 1:
            unscrambled_words.append(word)
    return unscrambled_words
```

vocab: is a dictionary that contains around 170 000 words. I put these word in a Python list.

letterset: is a list of letters. For example: ['x','d','a','a','o','u','e','g','g','m','n','f'].

The following code runs for 10 hours but has not finished yet. It's still running as I'm typing this post.

```
unscrambled_list = []
for i in range(0,100000):
    possib_words = possible_words(es_vocab,list(letterset_list[i]))
    unscrambled_list.append(possib_words)
```

Example vocabulary dictionary:
`es_vocab = ['ame', 'amo', 'año', 'apio', 'ema', 'empaño', 'me', 'mi', 'miope', 'opima', 'paño', 'pe', 'peña', 'pi', 'pia', 'pie', 'piña', 'pio', 'poema', 'a', 'o', 'e', 'xl', 'kl', 'ml']` #The last 3 values are not actual words

Example letterset:

```
letterset_list = ['oiwóeaópñmóó']
```

It would be awesome if someone shows me a faster way to achieve this task!

Comment: FYI you can just use a `collections.Counter` instead of your `charCount` (it does exactly the same thing), also you shouldn't name a variable `dict` as that shadows the built-in type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about collections.Counter. Also, indeed, it's a bad naming for a variable as 'dict.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
es_vocab = ['ame', 'amo', 'año', 'apio', 'ema', 'empaño', 'me', 'mi', 'miope', 'opima', 'paño', 'pe', 'peña', 'pi', 'pia', 'pie', 'piña', 'pio', 'poema', 'a', 'o', 'e', 'xl', 'kl', 'ml']

from itertools import combinations

def generate_key(w):
    out = []
    for ch in set(w):
        out.append( (ch, w.count(ch)) )
    return out

#build index
index = {}
for word in es_vocab:
    index.setdefault(frozenset(generate_key(word)), []).append(word)

letterset_list = ['oiwóeaópñmóó']

seen_substrings = set()
for x in letterset_list:
    all_substrings = (''.join(l) for i in range(len(x)) for l in combinations(x, i+1))
    for substring in all_substrings:
        substring = ''.join(sorted(substring))
        if substring in seen_substrings:
            continue
        seen_substrings.add(substring)
        key = frozenset(generate_key(substring))
        if not key in index:
            continue
        for word in index[key]:
            print(word)
```

Prints:

```
o
e
a
pi
mi
pe
me
pio
año
amo
pie
pia
ame
ema
apio
paño
piña
peña
miope
opima
poema
empaño
```

EDIT: Generating 100_000 lettersets and checking them against the `es_vocab` took on my machine:

```
real    10m42,351s
user    10m38,069s
sys 0m3,854s
```

EDIT 2: Now handles words with duplicate letters correctly.

Comment: I'm really looking forward for your answer, and since you're actually measuring the time it took. (Just in case) I want to point out that the es_vocab has around 170 000 words in it.

Comment: @Gam780 That's shouldn't be a problem, because we have `index` which is dict, so looking up the value in dict is O(1).

Comment: This works fast! Also, this is actually a correct way to do it. After comparing your method with the method that I posted. I found out that my solution is actually wrong! Still trying to figure out why my solution found fewer words than yours. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
def charCount(s):
    s = s.lower()
    answer = [0]*26
    for char in s: answer[ord(char)-97] += 1
    return tuple(answer)


def preprocess(vocab):
    answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for word in vocab: answer[charCount(word)].append(word)
    return answer


def possible_words(vocab, scrambled):
    '''note that the `vocab` parameter is actually intended to be preceprocess(list_of_dictionary_words)'''

    return vocab[charCount(scrambled)]

def get_all_possible_words(vocab, lettersets):
    vocab = preprocess(vocab)
    answer = {}
    for letterset in lettersets:
        answer[tuple(letterset)] = possible_words(vocab, letterset)
    return answer
```

Comment: Did not actually work for me since few letters in Spanish would be outside of the Unicode code point range you defined in the first function. E.g. charCount('abajeños')

Comment: @Gam780: you could get around that by simply replacing `ord(char)-97` with the unicode value and appropriately increasing the vector size

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach it something like this:

```
def contains_word(letters, word):
    return all(char in letters for char in word)
```

And make sure `letters` is a `set`